# Powershell displays extra characters in output

Tags: powershell, hashicorp-otto

I'm using Otto to setup a dev environment, and working from Powershell. Powershell inserts extra characters instead of what seems like it should be colors in the output. How can I change the Powershell configuration to display the output properly?

```
PS C:\dev\otto\discourse> otto dev
←[0m←[1m==> Creating local development environment with Vagrant if it doesn't exist...←[0m
←[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround for my problem. Using PowerShell ISE seems to display the error messages in a much more readable format.

[In PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Gj8.png)

[In PowerShell ISE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5F6f.png)